# Window functions cause awful execution plan when called from a view with external parametrized 'where' clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, window-functions

I had this issue long time ago, I found a workaround which suited me and forgot about it.

But now there's [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199029/why-would-an-odbc-query-against-mssql-2008sp2-take-100-times-as-long-as-the-same) on SO so I'm willing to bring this problem up.

There's a view that joins few tables in a very straightforward way (orders + order lines).

When queried without a `where` clause, the view returns several million lines.
However, noone ever calls it like that. The usual query is

```sql
select * from that_nasty_view where order_number = 123456;
```

This returns about 10 records out of 5m.

An important thing: the view contains a window function, `rank()`, which is partitioned exactly by the field using which the view is always queried:

```sql
rank() over (partition by order_number order by detail_line_number)
```

Now, if this view is queried with literal parameters in the query string, exactly as shown above, it returns the rows instantly. The execution plan is fine:

- Index seek on both tables using the indices on `order_number` (returns 10 rows).
- Calculating windows over the returned tiny result.
- Selecting.

However, when the view is called in a parametrized way, things get nasty:

- `Index scan` on all tables ignoring indices. Returns 5m rows.
- Huge join.
- Calculating windows over all `partition`s (about 500k windows).
- `Filter` to take 10 rows out of 5m.
- Select

This happens in all cases when parameters are involved. It can be SSMS:

```sql
declare @order_number int = 123456;
select * from that_nasty_view where order_number = @order_number;
```

It can be an ODBC client, such as Excel:

```sql
select * from that_nasty_view where order_number = ?
```

Or it can be any other client that uses parameters and not sql concatenation.

If the window function is removed from the view, it runs perfectly quickly, regardless of whether or not it's queried with parameters.

My workaround was to remove the offending function and reapply it at a later stage.

But, what gives? Is it genuinely a bug in how SQL Server 2008 handles window functions?

Comment: order_number is primary key? Datatypes of column and parameter match?

Comment: `order_number` is not a primary key. It is `int not null` with nonclustered index on it in both tables.

Comment: SQL Server 2005 had issues with [predicate pushing](http://jahaines.blogspot.com/2010/03/performance-tuning-101-what-you-will_17.html) in this area. I thought they were fixed now. BTW your TSQL example uses a variable not a parameter. Does adding `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` help?

Comment: @MartinSmith `option(recompile)` does help. That'd be another workaround I guess (the one I couldn't use because not all target cliens could append an `option` to a query).

Comment: @GSerg - SQL Server doesn't do variable sniffing and can fall back on default guesses that 10% of rows will match an `=` predicate. Are actual vs estimated rows way out? Also you can [set up a plan guide](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895390.aspx) to match the query and add the hint to it if the clients can't append `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: @MartinSmith I understand all that; what wonders me is the peculiar combination of four things: 1) the index on `order_number` has utter selectivity; 2) the window function partitioned on exactly that field so it is known prior to execution that all other order_numbers are not relevant to it; 3) when the window function is removed from the view the query does the right thing in all cases, sniffing or not; 4) estimated totally equals actual on all stages - the server KNOWS it's about to dig through the whole database, at it seems to enjoy it.

Comment: @GSerg - So on the bad plan with the filter last it has an estimated 5 million rows into the filter and an estimated 10 rows out matching the actual? If so maybe it is that predicate pushing issue still not fixed completely then.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, [pretty much so](http://i.stack.imgur.com/XZehl.png).

Comment: [Also see this answer on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15304023/73226)

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be a long standing issue that keeps resurfacing in one form or another and is still present in SQL Server 2012.

Some posts discussing it are

- [Performance Tuning 101 - 2005](http://jahaines.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/performance-tuning-101-what-you-will_17.html)
- [Plan Regression with Sequence Projections - 2008 R2](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/727419/plan-regression-with-sequence-projections) [@Paul White](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1192/sql-kiwi)
- [Common Table Expressions (CTEs), Window Functions, and Views - 2012](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/ctes-window-functions-and-views/) [@Jonathan Kehayias](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/931/jonathan-kehayias)
- [The Problem with Window Functions and Views](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/03/t-sql-queries/the-problem-with-window-functions-and-views)

All current versions of SQL Server up to and including 2012 are not able to push the filter on a partitioning group past the sequence project for a parameterised predicate except if `option(recompile)` is used (if 2008+).

An alternative to the `recompile` hint would be to rewrite the query to use a parameterised inline TVF as suggested by [@a1ex07](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/12503/22336))

Answer (score 3):

I'd try replacing the view by table-valued udf. That way it will filter records first, and then apply window function. This function may accept table parameter so you can pass multiple `order_number` into it

Comment: Yet another workaround, yes. I couldn't do that though because not all clients were able to consume a table-valued function.

Comment: Why? I'm not 100% sure, but I think all you need is to change query a little to something like `SELECT * FROM my_funct(12345)`

Comment: One of the requirement was the query is consumable by end users using Excel (that is, by MS Query), and MS Query will not let you do that, at least in versions up to 2003.

Comment: `it will filter records first, and then apply window function` is incorrect. [There is no deterministic order to execution](http://rusanu.com/2011/08/10/t-sql-functions-do-no-imply-a-certain-order-of-execution/)